# How to String.Format decimal with unlimited decimal places?

Tags: c#

I need to convert a decimal number to formatted string with thousand groups and unlimited (variable) decimal numbers:

```
1234 -> "1,234"
1234.567 -> "1,234.567"
1234.1234567890123456789 -> "1,234.1234567890123456789"
```

I tried `String.Format("{0:#,#.#}", decimal)`, but it trims any number to max 1 decimal place.

Comment: Be aware that the [decimal type has a precision of 28-29 digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use # multiple times (see [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)):

```
string.Format("{0:#,#.#############################}", decimalValue)
```

Or, if you're just formatting a number directly, you can also just use [decimal.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx) with the format string.

However, there is no way to include "*unlimited* decimal numbers".  Without a library supporting arbitrary precision floating point numbers (for example, using something like [BigFloat](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/documentation/reference/extreme.mathematics.bigfloat.aspx) from [Extreme Numerics](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/)), you'll run into precision issues eventually.  Even the [decimal type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) has a limit to its precision (28-29 significant digits).  Beyond that, you'll run into other issues.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not a general solution for all decimal types (like double).

Comment: @jurev: It is, but only to the limit of precision of the type in question.  As I said, all standard floating point types have a limited precision - you can only work to the precision of the type.

Comment: @jurev: `double` is not a decimal type, it's a binary floating point with limited precision.

Comment: @jurev to be precise, 15-16 digits http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

Answer (score 9):

As I've said, the decimal type has a precision of 28-29 digits.

```
decimal mon = 1234.12345678901234567890123M;
var monStr = mon.ToString("#,0.##############################");
var monStr2 = String.Format("{0:#,0.##############################}", mon);
```

Here there are 30x`#` after the decimal separator :-)

I've changed one `#` with `0` so that `0.15` isn't written as `.15` .

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
string DecimalToDecimalsString(decimal input_num)
        {            
            decimal d_integer = Math.Truncate(input_num); // = 1234,0000...
            decimal d_decimals = input_num-d_integer; // = 0,5678...

            while (Math.Truncate(d_decimals) != d_decimals)
                d_decimals *= 10; //remove decimals

            string s_integer = String.Format("{0:#,#}", d_integer);
            string s_decimals = String.Format("{0:#}", d_decimals);

            return s_integer + "." + s_decimals;
        }
```

replacing decimal with other types should work too.

Comment: Interesting solution, however it does not work for international formatting (some countries have even different 1000's group separators for integer and decimal part).