# How can I format a number but show all digits of precision?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, formatting

When a user goes to edit a number, I want to format a number to have a thousands separator in one case (and a percentage sign in another) but I want to be able to show absolutely all available digits of precision.

When the number is being displayed, its format is simply `{0:0,0;-0,0; - }`, (or `{0:0,0.00;-0,0.00; - }` to show two decimal places), but when my control goes into edit mode, I want to switch to displaying something very similar, but showing all available digits of precision. Is there any way to do this short of creating a format string that looks like this?

`{0:0,0.#############################;-0,0.###...`

I want to do something similar with percentages. I want to displayed value to be `{0:0.00 %;-0.00 %; - }` until the user activates the cell for editing, at which time the format should still be a percentage, but showing more digits of precision if they exist in the underlying value.

Thanks

Comment: will the "all available digits" not be determined by the actual numeric type? my point being, wouldn't that information be valuable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795161/c-sharp-how-to-string-format-decimal-with-unlimited-decimal-places) is similar to yours. (The answer is that it's not possible with the .NET built-in custom numeric formatting.)